# UINavigationController not pushing

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have two `UITableViews` embedded in a `UINavigationController`. The selection of a cell in the first table viewcontroller should trigger a push segue to the second. This segue is not being performed.

***FirstTableVC***

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   // getting called as planned
   if (indexPath.row == 0 && reload == YES) {
     // working
     [self pushedRefresh:self];
     reload = NO;
     return;
  }
  NSLog(@"past return"); // logged as planned
  // NOT performing!
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"more" sender:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
}
```

**What I've done/noticed**

- `SecondTblVC's` `viewDidLoad:` method is not being called. However, if I use non-push segues, the VC is presented correctly.
- I've tried using `nil` and `self` in the sender parameter for `performSegueWithIdentifier:` with the same results.
- I've converted the second view controller into a vanilla `UIViewController` with the same results.
- The "more" segue is correctly labeled and connected as `push`
- There's no crash, just lack of segue.
- I've deleted the entire `UINavigationController` setup in storyboard and replaced it with the same results.
- I do *not* have a separate .h/.m for the `UINavigationController`
- Table view `delegates/data source` links are working as planned.
- There *is* a `destinationViewController` (learned from logging in `performSegue` method).

Please let me know if more code and screenshots would help.

Thank you.

**Edit**
Here's my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` implementation:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ReuseCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = [clubNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [times objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How are you creating the segue in the storyboard?

Comment: Drag from UITableViewCell to SecondTblVC and select push.

Comment: OK, so you don't need to put the line [self performSegue...] in at all. If it is connected from the UITableViewCell then selecting the cell will call the segue anyway. Just remove that line.

Comment: Ok. Removed, but no change.

Comment: I'd suggest reading a tutorial on Ray wenderlich's site about using storyboards. It will guide you through this.

Comment: Do the cells being create in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` have the same identifier that is specified for the prototype cell in the storyboard?

Comment: If the identifiers do match, it might help if you post a screenshot of the storyboard.

Comment: The identifiers match (https://www.dropbox.com/s/f8amawlk7qsy9so/Screen%20Shot%202013-10-13%20at%207.46.23%20PM.png) I've posted the specified method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using table view controller instead of table view

- In your storyboard, create a storyboard ID for each of the `UITableViewControllers`, i.e.: vc1 and vc2
- In your vc1 function, lookup the storyboard ID for the second table view controller,
  which is :

> UITableViewController *vc2 = [self.storyboard
>   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc2"];
>   [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];

Comment: This has been solved. The problem was with a custom UiNavigationController class. Your suggestion was delineated in bullet 3.